# ts error code type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**i am getting this error code in angularjs, trying to create a countdown timer, please help**

```
//Convert the remainders gotten above to the nearest whole number
intervalinsecond = (intervalinsecond < 10) ? "0" + intervalinsecond : intervalinsecond;
intervalinminute = (intervalinminute < 10) ? "0" + intervalinminute : intervalinminute;
intervalinhour = (intervalinhour < 10) ? "0" + intervalinhour : intervalinhour;
//Get the value for day and output it throug the ID in the html table tags
document.getElementById("days").textContent = intervalinday;
document.getElementById("days").innerText = intervalinday;
//Get the value for hour and output it throug the ID in the html table tags
document.getElementById("hours").textContent = intervalinhour;
document.getElementById("hours").innerText = intervalinhour;
//Get the value for minute and output it throug the ID in the html table tags
document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = intervalinminute;
document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = intervalinminute;
//Get the value for second and output it throug the ID in the html table tags
document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = intervalinsecond;
document.getElementById("seconds").innerText = intervalinsecond;
```

Comment: What line has that error?

Comment: all this line;
 intervalinsecond = (intervalinsecond < 10) ? "0" + intervalinsecond : intervalinsecond;

Comment: "0" + intervalinsecond ??? what do you want to do?

Comment: @AnointingLawal Please post the rest of the code, or at least the code before this section. @Reflective I believe OP wants to display time like this: `HH:MM:SS`

Comment: the error shows that the var is numeric ... not a string

Comment: @ThomasDevries Wouldn't that make the error "type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'"? I haven't worked with TS too much though.

Comment: AngularJS timer ...

Comment: @Sidney That comment was my mistake. Misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `intervalinsecond` variable is a number, the result of the expression `(intervalinsecond < 10) ? "0" + intervalinsecond : intervalinsecond` can be either number or string depending on the `intervalinsecond` value. So, TS compiler infers type of this whole expression as `number | string`. But since it contains types other than `number` you cannot assign result of such an expression to a variable of type `number`. This is what compiler complains about.

PS. Apart from that, it's not a good idea to use the same variable to hold some numeric value and to hold its formatted representation in the template. You'd want to use pipe to format raw numeric value as you want directly in the template not involving any component's code at all.